# Amcharts 5 Separate Label into points with the same date

Tags: amcharts, amcharts5

I use AmCharts 5 and sometimes the data can come with a different value but with the same date

Result example:

```
[
  {"result":"AAA","date":"2022-06-09T23:00:00","value":155},
  {"result":"BBB","date":"2022-06-10T07:00:00","value":25},
  {"result":"CCC","date":"2022-06-11T07:00:00","value":85},
  {"result":"DDD","date":"2022-06-12T07:00:00","value":65},
  {"result":"EEE","date":"2022-06-12T08:00:00","value":198},
]
```

But when there is more than one record on the same date, it shows the points, but there is an equal Label for all points.

[image]

My code is:
https://jsfiddle.net/sNniffer/9xk6q3eu/17/

I need each point to have its Label, even if they are on the same date

Answer (score 0):

In your example, date strings are all unique!

The easiest solution here is to use **hour** as `timeUnit` in the settings of your `DateAxis`.

```js
am5.ready(function() {

  var root = am5.Root.new("chartdiv");

  var chart = root.container.children.push(am5xy.XYChart.new(root, {}));

  var xAxis = chart.xAxes.push(am5xy.DateAxis.new(root, {
    baseInterval: {
      timeUnit: "hour", // Put "hour" instead of "day"
      count: 1
    },
    renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererX.new(root, {}),
    tooltip: am5.Tooltip.new(root, {})
  }));

  var yAxis = chart.yAxes.push(am5xy.ValueAxis.new(root, {
    renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererY.new(root, {})
  }));
  
  var cursor = chart.set("cursor", am5xy.XYCursor.new(root, {
    xAxis: xAxis
  }));
  cursor.lineY.set("visible", false);

  var series = chart.series.push(am5xy.SmoothedXLineSeries.new(root, {
    name: "Series",
    xAxis: xAxis,
    yAxis: yAxis,
    categoryXField: "result",
    valueXField: "date",
    valueYField: "value",
    tooltip: am5.Tooltip.new(root, {
      labelText: "[bold]Result:[/] {categoryX}\n[bold]Date:[/] {valueX.formatDate()}\n[bold]Value:[/] {valueY}"
    })
  }));

  series.fills.template.setAll({
    visible: true,
    fillOpacity: 0.2
  });
  
  series.bullets.push(function() {
    return am5.Bullet.new(root, {
      sprite: am5.Circle.new(root, {
        radius: 8,
        stroke: root.interfaceColors.get("background"),
        strokeWidth: 2,
        interactive: false,
        fill: series.get("fill")
      })
    });
  });
 
  var data = [
    {result: "AAA", date: new Date("2022-06-09T23:00:00").getTime(), value: 155},
    {result: "BBB", date: new Date("2022-06-10T07:00:00").getTime(), value: 25},
    {result: "CCC", date: new Date("2022-06-11T07:00:00").getTime(), value: 85},
    {result: "DDD", date: new Date("2022-06-12T07:00:00").getTime(), value: 65},
    {result: "EEE", date: new Date("2022-06-12T08:00:00").getTime(), value: 198}
  ];
  
  series.data.setAll(data);
     
});
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/index.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/xy.js"></script>

<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```